# Actualizar y mostrar datos actualizados en Android Studio y SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server

Tengo un problema al actualizar o modificar datos en android studio, si ingreso a un usuario cualquiera y le agrego el 'correo', le doy 'guardar' y en base de datos si lo agrega (utilizo SQLServer) pero en el campo no lo muestra a menos que cierre sesión y vuelva a ingresar, existe algun metodo para volver a consultar la base de datos y me pueda mostrar el correo ingresado?.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Estimados, eviten ponerle negativos a usuarios que tienen 1 punto de reputación, recién están conociendo la plataforma, mejor hagan como el buen @Alfabravo que se tomó el tiempo de colocar un buen comentario explicando los detalles, gracias :D